# sscanf usage on matrix of unknown size?

Tags: c, arrays, string, matrix, scanf

So, I have a file that contains a matrix of NxM size. For example:

```
P2
3 3 1
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

The 'P2' is just an useless indicator, the first '3' indicates how many columns are and the second '3' indicates how many lines, '1' indicates the maximum value among the matrix's numbers. This matrix was stored in a data structure like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int c; // columns
    int l; // lines
    unsigned char max; // max value
    unsigned char** data // variable to store matrix's numbers
} Matrix;
```

To store the numbers from file to the data variable, I used the fread function, like this:

```
Matrix* newMatrix = NULL;
newMatrix = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));

FILE* fp = NULL;
fp = fopen(matrixfile, "r");

long size;
fseek(matrixfile, 0, SEEK_END);
size = ftell(matrixfile);
newMatrix->data = malloc(size);

// Jump the 'P2' bytes.
fseek(matrixfile, 2, SEEK_SET);

// Get the c, l and max values.
fscanf(matrixfile, "%i %i %i", &newMatrix->c, &newMatrix->l, &newMatrix->max);

// Jump a '\n' character.
fseek(matrixfile, 1, SEEK_CUR);

// Get matrix's numbers.
fread(newMatrix->data, 1, size, matrixfile);
```

Ok, I have the matrix's numbers stored as a string in the 'unsigned char** data' variable. But now I need to work with those numbers, so I'm trying to transform this string into a matrix of integers. I tried to do something like this:

```
void StringtoInt (Matrix* str){

int matrixAux[str->l][str->c], i, j;
for(i=0; i<str->l; i++)
    for(j=0; j<str->c; j++)
        sscanf(str->data, "%i ", &matrixAux[i][j]);
}
```

Well, I understand why this doesn't work and why my 'matrixAux' will be a CxL matrix with only 1's. But I cannot think of any way to work with sscanf without knowing how many elements are in the matrix.

So, my question: is there a better way to transform the 'unsigned char** data' string into a integer matrix WITHOUT changing the 'data' type (unsigned char**)?

I think maybe I'm just using the wrong method to store the file's matrix into the data variable (fread function), or messing up with the pointer to pointer syntax. But I also don't see any other good alternative to do that.

Comment: You can abstract from file positions (fseek, ftell) and just consider the matrix file a sequence of string tokens; scanf is perfectly suited to convert these strings into integers, directly from file (no need to fread the whole file first). Scanf will also just ignore any whitespace which may be present in the file (what if there is a trailing space somewhere?).

Comment: in addition to using `fscanf` to obtain the values from the file, you can also read an entire line at a time and use `strtoul` to extract an unknown number of values from each line. Nothing more right or wrong about either, but if you find yourself in need of finer grain error checking on your read of numbers, look at `strtol/strtoul` which provide a great deal of information about failures in the conversion process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1: Computing the size of `data`**

If the matrix is stored as a text file, just like you have posted, using

```
fseek(matrixfile, 0, SEEK_END);
size = ftell(matrixfile);
```

to come up with the size of `data` is not correct.

All you have to do is read the number of rows and the number of columns and then, you can use `numRows * numCols` to come up with the size of `data`.

**Problem 2: Allocating memory for `data`**

Use of

```
newMatrix->data = malloc(size);
```

to allocate memory for `data` seems to indicate a lack of understanding of how memory is allocated.

Type of `data` is `char**`.

`malloc(size)` allocates memory for an array of characters of size `size`. Assigning the return value of `malloc(size)` to `newMatrix->data` is wrong.

What you need is:

```
newMatrix->data = malloc(numRows*sizeof(char*)); // Assuming you read numRows first.
for ( int i = 0; < numRows; ++i )
{
   newMatrix->data[i] = malloc(numCols);
}
```

**Reading the data**

Now you can read the data from the file using:

```
for ( int i = 0; < numRows; ++i )
{
   for ( int j = 0; j < numCols; ++j )
   {
      int number;
      if ( fscanf(matrixfile, "%d", &number) == 1 )
      {
         // Check that number is within range.
         // ...

         newMatrix->data[i][j] = number;
      }
      else
      {
         // Unable to read the number.
         // Deal with the error.
         exit(1);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see! Didn't thought about the allocation problem right there, it works perfectly now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To scan a number directly into a `unsigned char`, use `"hhu"`  (`"hh"` available since C99)

```
sscanf(str->data, "%hhu", &matrixAux[i][j]);
```

---

As a text file `fseek(matrixfile, 2, SEEK_SET);` is UB.  Can only seek to the start, beginning or to a previous `tell()` offset.  Instead, seek to beginning and `fscanf(matrixfile, "P2 %i %i %i", &newMatrix->c, &newMatrix->l, &newMatrix->max);`.  Always check `fscanf()` results.