# C: How to take an input as unknown sized matrix

Tags: arrays, c, scanf

Question:
Given a matrix A, compute the sum of maximal elements row-wise (find a maximum element of each row and take their sum) and column-wise independently and return those values.

In which input is going to be :
First-line contains n, m number of rows and columns of input matrix.
Next n lines contains m integers.

Some examples:

Input1:

```
3 3
4 3 2 
3 7 7 
2 6 0
```

Output1:

```
17 18
```

Input2:

```
3 4
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
```

Output2:

```
24 42
```

I can't tell how I am supposed to take the matrix input using scanf. Please help.

Comment: `scanf()` pays no heed to newlines except as a separator between numbers.  The doesn't matter though; you can read a number on each iteration, knowing whether it is (another) number in the current row or the start of a new row.  At the end of a row, you can accumulate the row max you've been saving into the overall sum.  You only need five variables: number of columns, number of rows, most recent input number in current row, maximum value in current row, and overall sum of max values.

Comment: Similar [sscanf usage on matrix of unknown size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958291/sscanf-usage-on-matrix-of-unknown-size) @JonathanLeffler -- that is the "New Math", get with it `:)` I think that is `4 + 8 + 12 = 24` and `9 + 10 + 11 + 12 = 42`. (last col, last row)

Comment: Are you asking `"How to take an input as unknown sized matrix?"`, or since you are given the rows as columns on the first line `"How to declare storage for a matrix of any given size?"` In the first case, you would ignore the first line and just allocated dynamically as you go, in the second case, you can simply allocate for the entire matrix to begin with (with either pointers and row-allocations, or in a single allocation and then simulate a 2D array from a single allocated block)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I partially misread the question.  And given that you need to find the maximum in each column too, you need some more variables — probably an array sized for the number of columns.  That can probably be a VLA.  Or you can limit the size needed somehow.

Comment: Yes a VLA would provide a simple solution, but given their now optional support, a VLA plus some guaranteed alternative would probably be the best bet. I wish the standard would provide a bit more certainty surrounding the fate of the VLA.

Answer (score 0):

just use scanf("%d", &variable) no matter if delimiter is a new line or a space:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int lines, cols;
    scanf("%d", &lines);
    scanf("%d", &cols);
    for(int y = 0; y < lines; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < lines; x++){
            int variable;
            scanf("%d", &variable);
            // your code
        }
    }
    // your code
    return 0;
}
```